# Is there a term for wine poured for a kosher libation?

Tags: words, talmud-gemara

Yayin nesach is the term used for libation wine poured for idol worship.

Is there a term for wine offered on the Altar in a kosher sacrifice?

Comment: Interesting to note that for some reason, the Gemarah uses this term related to *avodah zarah* when, in the Torah itself, we see the term *nesech* or *nisko* constantly used to refer to Jewish (altar) sacrifices. I wonder what the history of that change is and why? (Similar to the drastic change in meaning for *am ha'aretz*).

Comment: Something like "nesech sheichar"?

Comment: @DanF  The different meanings of am ha'aretz are described here http://www.torah.org/learning/rambam/talmudtorah/tt3.2.html

Comment: @danf Not so consistently. What about ישתו יין נסיכם (Devarim 32:38)?

Comment: @Shamiach Good find!

Comment: Can you source your first sentence?

Comment: It could be because today we have not 'nsochim' but we do have 'nesech'.

Comment: @cham  Please explain your last comment (or question) more fully.

Comment: Well we call it nesech because we dont have the 'nesech' of korbonus today. @YehudaW

Comment: Wasn't the yayin hameshumar used?

Answer (score 2):

It's called nesachim, as in Pesachim 42b: "When they used to bring nesachim from Yehuda, their wine wouldn't spoil."

Comment: Would that word refer to water poured on the Altar also?

Comment: @YehudaW Yes. There was ניסוך המים and ניסוך היין.

Comment: @double-aa  Are you saying the term nesachim does not pertain only to wine, but could refer to water as well?

Comment: @YehudaW *nisuch hamayim* refers to the water libation on Succos.

Comment: @YehudaW 'Nesachim' means 'libations'. It says nothing about what was being libated or to whom or why. 'Yayn Nesech' means 'wine of libation' without saying to whom or why it is being libated. 'Nissuch hamitz tappuzim' means "the libation of orange juice". These are just words. Use them, like all words, to say whatever you mean to say.

Comment: @YehudaW Actually, the term nesachim is sometimes used to mean all the stuff that goes along with a korban: wine that's poured, and flour-and-oil that's burned.

Comment: @double-aa  Are you saying this answer is wrong, that  nesachim is not a term for wine offered on the Altar in a kosher sacrifice?

Comment: @YehudaW No, I'm saying that it has a more specific meaning (like Double AA said) as well as a more general one.